# Why am I unable to map this array of objects when it is loaded in useState()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

learning React but I'm trying to map an array of objects in a dropdown box.

I'm getting a "Uncaught TypeError: ids.map is not a function".

Why am I getting this error when I have set the loadedIds I get from the GET request into  useState's setIds?

https://jsfiddle.net/4jh9c6dv/53/

Thank you for helping a beginner :')

```js
function Dropdown ()
{
    const [ids, setIds] = React.useState([]);

 React.useEffect(() => {
    request.get(endpointIds).then((response) => {
      setIds(response.data);
      
      const loadedIds = [];
      
      for (const id in response)
      {
        loadedIds.push({
        id: ids,
        });
      }
      
      setIds(loadedIds);
      
    });
  }, []);
  
  
 const idsList = ids.map((id) => 
 (
        <option>id</option>
 ));
```

Comment: Your push doesn't just push the number it pushes an object with the key id pointing to the ids state object. Are you sure you don't want `loadedIds.push(id)`? I don't think this actually adds any of the loaded data to your state. Try console.log ing your ids before the map.

Comment: `console.log(response.data)` will also help... `console.log()` every variable to debug... `console.log` is your friend. 

Comment: @nlta Thanks for pointing that out. I'm one step closer. Where should I grabbing the value of the iD because currently my drop down is just showing the array index https://jsfiddle.net/ghe8fmcn/44/

Comment: @Trav typically in HTML options are created like this with a value and human readable text. `<option value="machine_readable_id">User facing text</option>` I'm not sure what the appropriate value/text are here. That'll depend on what you're showing the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use `setIds(response.data);`. Remove that.
`response.data` is not an array, `response.data.ids` is. That is why you get the error.

**EDIT** : Use `for of` instead of `for in`.

[`for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) is used to iterate over items of an array/iterable object.
`for in` is used to iterate over index.

Comment: Also, `loadedIds.push({id: ids});` should just be `loadedIds.push({id});`

Comment: @Tushar Shahi Thanks for pointing that out. I'm one step closer. Where should I be grabbing the value of the iD because currently my drop down is just showing the array index instead of the value jsfiddle.net/ghe8fmcn/44

Comment: I have edited the answer. Also please try to include all related questions in the post itself so people coming in later can understand

Comment: @TusharShahi Thank you for teaching me JS and stackoverfly ediquette!

Answer (score 0):

response.data should be response.data.id
you also forgot curly braces {id}